# What does the leading colon mean in a string representing path in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I recently saw the following piece of PyQt GUI code:

```
QIcon(":/image/images/search.png")
```

What does the leading colon in the path string mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that the path is an [application resource](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#using-resources-in-the-application) instead of a full filepath.

Comment: Is it only a *qt* special thing?

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil: Yes.